# UploadCollection - upload status doesn't show

Tags: sapui5

I want to use the UI5 [UploadCollection](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.UploadCollection/preview).
Everything works fine, apart from the fact that the upload status is not displayed to me.. I copied the code from the sample and changed the upload url.. but I can't see status.

Does anybody know what to do?

```
<UploadCollection
    id="uploadCollection"
    items="{/files}"
    change="onChange"
    selectionChange="onSelectionChange"
    uploadComplete="onUploadComplete"
    beforeUploadStarts="onBeforeUploadStarts"
    uploadUrl="...../js/upload.xsjs">
    <items>
        <UploadCollectionItem
            documentId="{DOCUMENT_ID}"
            fileName="{FILE_NAME}"
            mimeType="{mimeType}"
            enableEdit="false">
        </UploadCollectionItem>
    </items>
</UploadCollection>
```

As already said, the upload works. My concern is the status information...

Comment: Your UploadCollectionItem does not have a status as in the example. So why do you expect a status to be shown?

Comment: @matbtt, I use the same code as above, just added a `model.refresh()`on the `beforeUpload`event and now I'm getting an upload status.. obviously this xml is fine (for whatever reason)..

Answer (score 0):

Just added a `model.refresh` on the `beforeUpload`and everything works fine...